# How to make TextMeshProUGUI truncate the left part (beginning) of a line?

Tags: unity, unity-ui, text-mesh-pro

I'm trying to display file names including their directory. When the file path gets too long for the text box, I want to align it right, because the filename is more important than the directory.

I can change the alignment, but the text is still truncated on the right hand side, instead of culling the beginning of the line.
Is there a way to do that without using masks?

I'm also having a hard time detecting overflow. For some reason it is only set to true if I have wrapping enabled, which I don't want.

Comment: Text should get truncated based on length, not on alignment. Just check for the length of your string and if it is too long for your display, just grab the file name only. If you encounter a problem with that, you should post more of your code and what went wrong

Comment: What do you mean by length, number of chars?

Comment: Number of characters isn't enough. It depends on the details of the rendering given variable spaced fonts. There might be a thing in the textmesh object that can tell you what the rendered width is in pixels before setting it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was confused by the word 'length'. I think it needs to be set to wrapping, bc. truncate takes care of that anyways. Not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method with

```
x = characterInfo[i].info.vertex_BL.position.x;
```

failed for some rect settings, so I fell back to @DMGregory's xAdvance method. I did modify it to be used with input fields as well:

```
static void truncateText(TMP_InputField inputField){
    TMP_Text textField = inputField.textComponent;
    string text = textField.text;
    int lastIndex = text.Length - 1;
    if (lastIndex < 10) //isNullOrEmpty as well as isNullOrWhitespace do not return true reliably
    {
        return; // 8 chars always fit
    }
    // force it to calculate the character layout.
    textField.ForceMeshUpdate();
    TMP_TextInfo textInfo = textField.textInfo;

    // Get the range between the first and last character in the line.        
    float start = textInfo.characterInfo[0].origin;
    float end = textInfo.characterInfo[lastIndex].xAdvance;
    float budget = textField.rectTransform.rect.width;

    int i;
    for (i = lastIndex; i > -1; i--)
    {
        TMP_CharacterInfo info = textInfo.characterInfo[i];
        start = info.origin;
        if (end - start > budget) break;
    }

    // Take only characters to the right of our first overflow.
    inputField.SetTextWithoutNotify(text.Substring(i + 1));
}
```

This method assumes, you have already set the text of the input field's text component and stored it somewhere, if you ever need it again.
Also: don't forget to restore the original text, if a user clicks into the field (On Select)

Comment: Keep in mind that the vertices sit some extra padding distance outside the visible shape of the letter, to give room for the signed distance falloff, so you might get more consistent or intuitive results using other character metrics.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'd rather cut off one letter too many than leave one that's outside the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

We could do this with a script that takes the text on behalf of the TextMeshPro, tries to layout the full string, and if it doesn't fit, takes only the subset of characters at the end of the string that does fit, and passes those on to the TextMeshPro instead.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

[RequireComponent(typeof(TMP_Text))]
public class LeftElidedText : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Cache the full text, so our truncation doesn't destroy our only copy.
    [SerializeField]
    string _text;
    public string text {
        get => _text;

        set {
            if (_text == value) return;

            _text = value;
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    TMP_Text _textMesh;

    void UpdateText() {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_text)) {
            _textMesh.text = "";
            return;
        }

        // Apply the whole text to the TextMeshPro and 
        // force it to calculate the character layout.
        _textMesh.text = _text;
        _textMesh.ForceMeshUpdate();
        var info = _textMesh.textInfo;

        // Get the range between the first and last character in the line.        
        var start = info.characterInfo[0].origin;
        var last = info.lineInfo[0].lastCharacterIndex;
        var end = info.characterInfo[last].xAdvance;        

        // Compare against our space budget in the Text's bounding rectangle.
        var budget = _textMesh.rectTransform.rect.width;

        // If the text fits already, accept it as is.
        if (end - start <= budget) return;

        // Otherwise, scan back until we find the first character that overflows.
        int i;
        for (i = last; i >= 0; i--) {
            var c = info.characterInfo[i];
            start = c.origin;
            if (end - start > budget) break;
        }

        // Take only characters to the right of our first overflow.
        _textMesh.text = _text.Substring(i + 1);
    }

    // Handle invoking the setter in-editor.
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    string _previousText;
    void OnValidate() {
        TryGetComponent(out _textMesh);

        if (_text != _previousText) {
            UpdateText();
        }
        _previousText = _text;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. However I think it's too much of a hack for me. I went to masking after all, deciding the alingment when I detect overflow. I do occasionally get tiny chunks of partial letters when the mask cuts through one, but I guess I'm ok with it

Comment: Want to post your solution as an Answer you can mark as Accepted?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this method instead, which is for measuring a string without setting it:

> Vector2 TMP_Text.GetPreferredValues(...)

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@3.2/api/TMPro.TMP_Text.GetPreferredValues.html?q=preferred